# Python Shell: Global name 't' is not define. Me: but it is

Tags: python, shell, global-variables

I imported a simple module into my Python shell. It contains just the following function (what it does it not important for my problem)

```
 def generateMessages():
        messagesPerSecond = [getPoisson(rate1) for i in range(0, t)]
        messages = []
        while i < t:
            while j < messagesPerSecond[i]:
                millisecond = round(random.random(), 3)
                messages.append(i + millisecond)
                j += 1
            i += 1
```

When I want to test this out in shell, I set the variables

```
t = 100
rate1 = 3
```

and call `generateMessages()`.

But then I get an error `NameError: global name 't' is not defined`.
But it is defined!

Why is this happening? How do I stop this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Globals in the shell are not the same globals as what `generateMessages()` sees. Each module has their own.

Set `t` *in the module `generateMessages()` is defined in*.

You can do this dynamically:

```
>>> import yourmodule
>>> yourmodule.t = 100
>>> yourmodule.rate1 = 3
```